# Click button and get text with CeFSharp

Tags: javascript, html, cefsharp

I'm creating a program in vb.net to go to https://www.royalmail.com/track-your-item#/ and:

1. Enter some text in the Reference Number box
2. Click the button 'Track your delivery'
3. Grab the text from the page so I can search for the delivery date

I've had to switch to using CeFSharp, as the microsoft browser doesn't want to load the page, so this is my first time with it.

This is what I have so far (CWB1 is the name of the browser object):

```
CWB1.LoadUrl("https://www.royalmail.com/track-your-item#")

CWB1.LoadUrl("javascript:void( document.getElementById( 'barcode-input' ).value='12345678' )")

Dim script = "var pagebutton = document.getElementById('submit');
pagebutton.click();"

CWB1.ExecuteScriptAsyncWhenPageLoaded(script)
```

The page loads, the text '12345678' is entered in the search box, but running the script to press the button does nothing.

I can't figure out how to press the button. I thought it must be the wrong id, but inspecting the web page seems to give button id="submit" so this should work? I've tried a few variations but nothing seems to move me forwards.

I also then need to grab the text from the page - not sure how to so this either?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Open Devtools to see what's going on. Check for errors, run your script to make sure it works. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#javascript-debugging Use an IIFE to wrap your script would be my suggestion. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE don't use LoadUrl to execute JavaScript.

Comment: I'd be checking if the website supports rest style urls, see if you can load the url directly rather than filling out the form. They may also have anti bot measures in place to prevent bots/automation.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't load the URL directly - it has to be generated from the button. I'm not much good with javascript, but I'll try your IIFE suggestion - thanks.

Comment: Forgot to mention - I believe they do have anti-bot measures, but I tried running some tests manually in a browser by just pasting in the text each time and got to 50 tries without any 'prove you're not a robot' stuff kicking in, so I may be OK. If not, I'll just have to handle that when it crops up.

Comment: Try run your scripts in DevTools first, make sure they work there. Most couriers here will send an email with a link to track your package, if they do the same you should be able to load the tracking directly if you can get an example.

Comment: Thanks - bit out of my depth looking at devtools, but I'll persevere. I don't think there's a link available - I know what you mean I've seen it with other couriers, but I think RM works by just giving you the reference number. It would certainly make it easier if there was one, so I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've found that the button press only works if you enter the text in the field via sendkey event. So the button press code was working after all - I guess the site's security is trying to make sure someone is typing the text in, instead of a robot. Thanks for your help with this amaitland!